# Hosting Static Files on Amazon Web Services > Amazon Bucket - Django - PNG - CSS files

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, hosting, static-files

I need to host my static files on AWS in order to sort out some problems I have been having with my Django website. I have been trying to solve this on and off for about a year now while finishing up the rest of the website but now it is the last thing to do and I can't put it off any longer. I have looked at the documentation and looked at so many videos with no luck. Below is everything I have including code and my bucket file configuration that pertains to this problem. Everything that I currently have running should be hosting all my static files on my Amazon Bucket, however, it isn't. I'm not getting an error but when I 'inspect' on google they are all being hosted locally. I have followed so many tutorials and started from scratch so many times and nothing is seeming to work. Thank You so much in advance.**What is wrong with the configuration below?** **Is MEDIA_URL affecting it?**

P.S. = The gallery folder I have in my bucket is for images that users upload and those images are successfully being hosted on AWS and working fine it's just the static. This means the connection to the bucket is working fine.

```
import django_heroku
from pathlib import Path
import os
from django_quill import quill

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
#BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))))
ROOT_DIR = os.path.dirname(BASE_DIR)
TEMPLATE_DIR = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')
#MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BAS_DIR, 'media')
TIME_INPUT_FORMATS = ['%I:%M %p',]

#Media_URL = '/signup/front_page/sheets/'


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'HERE BUT NOT SHOWN'
# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


#ADMIN_USERNAME = 'HERE BUT NOT SHOWN'
#ADMIN_PASSWORD = 'HERE BUT NOT SHOWN'
#AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = [
 #   'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
 #   'config.backends.SettingsBackend',
#]


EMAIL_BACKEND = 'django.core.mail.backends.console.EmailBackend'



# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'my_app',
    'django_quill',
    'tinymce',
    'ckeditor',

    'boto3',

    #'django_extensions',

    'storages',
    #'django-storages',

    'django_filters',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'inspect_list.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [TEMPLATE_DIR,],
        'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'inspect_list.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]


AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = 'HERE BUT NOT SHOWN'
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = 'HERE BUT NOT SHOWN'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'name1234'
AWS_S3_CUSTOM_DOMAIN = 'name1234.s3.amazonaws.com'
AWS_LOCATION = 'static'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATIC_URL = 'https://name1234.s3.amazonaws.com/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),
]


#AWS_S3_FILE_OVERWRITE = False
#AWS_DEFAULT_ACL = None
#DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'


#STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

#STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static'),)
#STATIC_URL = '/static/'


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'America/Cancun'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/howto/static-files/

MEDIA_URL = '/mediafiles/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'mediafiles')
AUTH_USER_MODEL = 'my_app.CustomUser'

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = 'front_page'
LOGOUT_REDIRECT_URL = 'login'

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: What is your _specific_ problem? All you say is "however, it isn't".

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Thank you for your response. To clarify... Everything seems to be properly configured according to several videos and even more documentation however the static files including the CSS and png files are still being hosted locally. The images that users can upload however still work and go into the 'gallery' folder in my bucket which proves that the connection from my website the bucket is set up correctly at the least. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The question is not clear. You're asking about static resources but the code you have shared is of Django and Heroku? How come Python / Django can be static? Which URL you're using to load your website? If you're using localhost then it can't be from S3 and if it's s3 URL then it can't be local.

Another problem I can guess is hardcoded wrong paths in static assets. You have to make all your paths "relative" for static S3 website hosting to work.

Another solution is to use CloudFront in front of S3 to route dynamic contents of your website to your Django application. You can host your Django app on Heruko or EC2 or ECS/EKS, etc. So 1 origin for S3 and 2nd origin for your python code.

Comment: I put the questions in bold above. I need to host my django static files on AWS bucket and not locally. My whole configuration seems to me to be correct and should be hosting them in my bucket but instead is still hosting them locally. What is wrong with my configuration that is preventing all of my static files from hosting on AWS? I'm thankful for your advice in your second paragraph but I am still a little confused. I haven't been able to find much information on relative static paths for S3. I also completely restarted and tried to go through S3 AND Cloud Front with no luck

Comment: First please clarify what is django static files? Django is a python framework which is backend technology. You CAN NOT use python files as static website. You need a server to execute python code for your site to run. Please mention what you mean by static content according to your definition. Or read up on these terms.

Comment: By Django static files I mean static files such as png and CSS files that are being hosted on my Python Django website. They are being hosted locally, I need them to be hosted on AWS. Yes, I have built a fully functioning website using the programming language Python with a web framework of Django. I apologize for my ignorance, I didn't know that I needed the clarify that. The static files I am referring to are the ones that are shown on my Python Django website. They are being loaded locally and I need them hosted non-locally as in on AWS servicing.

Comment: Do you have any guidance as to my problem?

Comment: Put all your static files (images, html, css, js) on S3 bucket and enable website hosting on that bucket. Use CloudFront with 2 origins (1 for your static assets pointing to S3, 2 your Django app hosted somewhere). Manage the routing of resources via "path" (Behaviour in CloudFront) YOUR-URL/static-assets(goes to s3) YOUR-URL/web (goes to django)